# VB.NET Can't hide login button after doing login successfully

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I already tried different methods, but I can't hide the button.
The objective is to only show login button and when we do the login successfully, the button goes Invisible and the other buttons show.

Here is Form "Inicio":

```
    Public LoginDone As String = "0"

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        hideSubmenu()

        If LoginDone = "0" Then
            btnLogin1.Visible = True
            btnInicio.Visible = False
            btnConta.Visible = False
        Else
            btnLogin1.Visible = False
            btnInicio.Visible = True
            btnConta.Visible = True
        End If

    End Sub
```

Form "Login":

```
  If table.Rows.Count = 0 Then

            MessageBox.Show("Login Inválido") 'Failed login

        Else

            MessageBox.Show("Iniciada sessão com sucesso") 'Sucess login

            Inicio.LoginDone = "1"

            Me.Hide()

        End If
```

Comment: Could you please share us a screen shot about your current result? Without result it is purely guess work. I can't clearly know your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form "Inicio":

```
Public Sub LoginState(ByVal result As Boolean)
    hideSubmenu()

    If result = True Then
        btnLogin1.Visible = True
        btnInicio.Visible = False
        btnConta.Visible = False
    Else
        btnLogin1.Visible = False
        btnInicio.Visible = True
        btnConta.Visible = True
    End If
    Me.Show()
End Sub
```

Form "Login":

```
If table.Rows.Count = 0 Then
    MessageBox.Show("Login Inválido") 'Failed login
    Login.LoginState(False)
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Iniciada sessão com sucesso") 'Sucess login
    Login.LoginState(True)
    Me.Hide()
End If
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed some things on your fix, but you really helped me get to my problem :)